# Resizable html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to crate a resizable div container by using the following method from jquery library https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

My code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
      <style>
      #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
      #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
      .ui-widget-content {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #333333;
    }
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It does not work.

There is no any error in the console log but I can not drag the border and change the size of it.

I can not see why there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for jquery-ui to work as expected you need the css file included:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css
```

Here is your code with the css file in it:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
} );
```

```css
#resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
#resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```